# Two Classes (A,B) - B to have a pointer to class A non-static method

Tags: c++, pointers

I have two classes that don't know anything about themselfs class A, class B.

Class A is called the ENGINE,
Class B is called the GUI.

I want GUI class to have a pointer to a function in class ENGINE, so that when an event occurs on GUIControl, it calls ENGINE member function with two parameters (int,int).

Here's how i would like to have it:

```
class CGUIManager
{
public:
    void SetControlCallback(void(*pFunctionPointer)(int,int) );

private:
    void (*m_pControlCallbackFunction)(int,int) ;
};
void CGUIManager::SetControlCallback(void(*pFunctionPointer)(int,int) )
{
    if(pFunctionPointer)
        m_pControlCallbackFunction = pFunctionPointer;
}

class CEngine
{
private:        
    void GUIControlsCallback(int iControlID, int iControlMessage);
    CGUIManager *pGUI;
};
```

Now while initializing ENGINE, i want to call:

```
//Set Controls Callback to CEngine Method 
pGUI->SetControlsCallback( GUIControlsCallback );
```

To register a callback within CGUIManager class, that points to a method in CEngine class.

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using an interface (or something like that) if you would like it to be oo instead of function pointers ( which must point to a static member btw )

```
class IGuiCallback
{
public:
    virtual void  GUIControlsCallback(int iControlID, int iControlMessage)=0;
};

class CGUIManager
{
public:
    void SetControlCallback(IGuiCallback*);

private:
    IGuiCallback* m_pCallback;
};

class CEngine:public IGuiCallback
{
public:
    void GUIControlsCallback(int iControlID, int iControlMessage);

private:
    CGUIManager *pGUI;
};
```

then in engine:

```
pGUI->SetCallback(this);
```

There may be some syntax errors in my code but you should get the picture

Comment: +1 definitely the way to go. If @PeeS is in control of the design/implementation

Comment: ++, Great approach, that's what we will use in this implementation. Thanks for sheding a light on me.

Comment: Obviously, I'd recommend against this: this unnecessarily couples `CEngine` and `CGUIManager`, not to mention that it prescribes the exact name of the function in the manager which is called. This dependency is entirely unnecessary when using a proper function object like `std::function<void(int, int)>`. ... which is, BTW, even simpler while offering better flexibility.

Comment: Just to confirm, works like a charm.
I know i have to coupple both CEngine and the Interface class, but that's enough - as long as it works.

Thanks again for a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers-to-member-functions are not function pointers in C++.

To call your callback later (using provided `SetControlsCallback` signature), the caller need to have a valid instance of CEngine. You can achieve that by binding the pointer to `CEngine` to GUIControlsCallback:

```
CEngine* pEngine; // initialized somewhere
pGUI->SetControlsCallback(std::bind1st(pEngine, GUIControlsCallback));
```

If you use Boost or C++11, you'd better use their versions of bindings (`boost::bind` or `std::bind` respectively).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to use `std::function<void(int, int)` as the type of the registered callback: this object can be used to call any function [object] which is callable with two `int`s. In particular, it could call the member function `CEngine::GUIControlsCallback(int, int)` which actually has three parameters:

1. the two obvious parameter to the member function of type `int`
2. the implicit pointer to the object (which becomes `this`)

The way this is done is to construct a function object which provides as first parameter a pointer to the `CEngine` object and takes two integers:

```
struct CEngine_bind {
    CEngine_bind(CEngine* engine): engine_(engine) {}
    void operator()(int i0, int i1) { this->engine_->GUIControlsCallback(i0, i1); }
    CEngine* engine_;
};
```

Alternatively, you can use `std:bind()` which is a create a suitably bound function:

```
CEngine engine; // ... wherever this object is coming from)
std::function<void(int, int)> callback(std::bind(&CEngine::GUIControlsCallback, &engine,
    std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

... and then set the `callback` object as the callback. This object simply be called passing two integer parameters which will cause the member function on the referenced object to be called:

```
callback(10, 20);
```

would call

```
engine.GUIControlsCallback(10, 20);
```

The `std::function<void(int, int)>` is copyable, i.e. you can easily store it in your `CGUIManager` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the interface of the CGUIManager class, I ssugest you generalise it to use `boost::function<void(int, int)>` (or `std::function` if writing in C++11) instead of a function pointer.

If you can't, unfortunately you are a victim of bad design. C-style callbacks that use function pointers usually allow for some kind of `void*` user data parameter to carry any additional information bound to the callback - in this case the your `CEngine` pointer could be cast to void* and a free function wrapper could be written to cast the `void*` back to `CEngine`. However, if you are able to change the callback interface, using boost/STL function is a superior technique.